# How to break out of a for loop using a function?

Tags: python

I'm running an if action defined in a function on a list of elements using a for loop. There is a secondary action within the first action. I want the for loop to stop once the action is successful the first time. Below is sample code to demonstrate:

```
my_list = [99, 101, 200, 5, 10, 20, 40]

def action(x):
    if x >= 100:
        print('It is finished')
        over_100 = True
        return over_100

def action2(x):
    x += 1
    action(x)
    
over_100 = False
for number in my_list:
    action2(number)
    if over_100:
        break
```

I want the for loop to stop at the first instance of >=100. For example, it should add 1 to 99 (first element of the list) and then stop everything. Instead, it is printing "It is finished" 3x because it loops through the whole list.

Comment: Make it return `True` or `False` which can be checked in the `for` loop.

Comment: One way is that you could `raise` an error in `action_function` and parse that error in the for loop with a `try/except` handling.

Comment: You need some return value from `action_function` to deal with.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any any seems like an option

Comment: @astrochun you could raise an error, but you shouldn't, unless the situation actually represents an error.

Comment: Fair point. I misunderstand why the for loop needed to terminate.

Comment: the function could also raise StopIteration, but it's not super explicit unless you create a subclass of StopIteration.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I tried some of the strategies. The problem I guess is that I have nested function actions and this solution is not working for that. See the edited question and code for an update.

Answer (score 9):

You can make the function return a value and check the value in the loop. And you can use `break` to break out of the loop.

```py
list_of_scopes = [scope1, scope2, scope3, etc.)

def action_function():
  return 'TEST' in xxxxx


for scope in list_of_scopes:
  found = action_function()
  if found:
    break
```

---

As of `Python 3.8` you could even use the walrus operator which makes for more readable code:

```
for scope in list_of_scopes:
    if found := action_function():
        # optionally do something with `found`
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

A totally different approach to show what I meant in my comment on the question:

```
from contexlib import suppress


class StopProcessing(StopIteration):
  pass


def action_function(param):
  if 'TEST' in param:
    print('TEST is found!')
    raise StopProcessing


with suppress(StopProcessing):
  for scope in list_of_scopes:
    action_function()
```

Comment: Cool - thanks for demonstrating suppress. hadn't heard of it before. contextlib is a gem

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_scopes = [scope1, scope2, scope3, etc.)

def action_function(param):
  found = False
  if 'TEST' in param:
    print('TEST is found!')
    found = True

  return found


for scope in list_of_scopes:
  result = action_function(scope)  # or whatever parameter
  if result:
    break
```

Comment: It's invalid syntax in Python to assign a value to the keyword `break`. This program does not run as is. Replacing the word `break` (within `action_function`) to any valid variable name would work.

Comment: @GregSadetsky thanks for pointing that out. I need some coffee after that nap I just woke up from, clearly

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `global`.

Global tells your function's scope to not create a new variable `over_100` but instead re-use an `over_100` that was declared in a higher scope.

I do prefer the other answers that return a value instead of polluting global scope.  Whatever works!

```
my_list = [99, 101, 200, 5, 10, 20, 40]
over_100 = False
def action(x):
    global over_100
    if x >= 100:
        print('It is finished')
        over_100 = True

def action2(x):
    global over_100
    x += 1
    action(x)
    if over_100:
        return
    # here is more work for action2 that you skip when over_100
    
for number in my_list:
    action2(number)
    if over_100:
        break
```

Output:

```
It is finished
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Allow me to add one more layer of complexity: what if the for loop has other actions below "action2(number)?" How can I prevent them from running for the current iteration once that over_100 is True?

Comment: @WTBHelbreath updated answer for your comments question